# DAX measure for Inventory Forecast

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, forecast

I am struggling to create a measure to calculate the current month inventory in my power BI report.

Below is the detailed explanation of the problem.

[image]

I have the measure for Sales Forecast ready which is average of past 3 months sales (Sales Actual) and is constant for all the future months. Eg., Sales Forecast for Jan'23 and after = Average(Oct'22 + Nov'22 + Dec'22)

But struggling to create a measure for Inventory Forecast.

**Inventory forecast (current month)= Inventory Forecast (previous month) + Shipments (current month) - Sales Forecast (current month)**

Eg., Inventory Forecast for Feb'23 = Inventory Forecast (Jan'23) + Shipments (Feb'23) - Sales Forecast (Feb''23)

If anyone can solve this then it'd be a big help for me.

Thanks.

I have tried to create a measure for inventory forecast but since it requires its own previous value, and there power bi throws the circular reference error.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in DAX, but I could show you how to do it in Power Query (`Transform Data` option) if that is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awesome resource to learn DAX semantics, patterns, and idioms. What you are asking is basic, but involves many fundamental aspects of DAX and PBI.

https://www.daxpatterns.com/comparing-different-time-periods/
https://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

Create two metrics, as follows:

```
Sales Forecast2
=divide(CALCULATE(sum(SalesTable[Sales Actual]),DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date],lastdate('Calendar'[Date]), -3,MONTH)), CALCULATE(COUNTA(SalesTable[Sales Actual]),DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date],lastdate('Calendar'[Date]), -3,MONTH)))

Invertory Forecast
=CALCULATE(sum('SalesTable'[Inventory Actual]),PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar'[Date])) + CALCULATE(sum(SalesTable[shipments])) + 'SalesTable'[Sales Forecast2]
```

The result as follows(excel 2016):
[image]

I create salestable and a calendar table, create relations between tables:
[image]